# Difference in Rendering Yii2 php tags

Tags: php, yii2

What is the difference between php tags in short hand notation as i am having problem getting a view render in Yii2 from the `<?php` tag but not from the `<?=` Sorry i just started learning yii2 but to the fact i know is that short hand notation of php and classic notation is both the same but why does it matter and how i can find out which one to use.

```html
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

use yii\helpers\Html;

$this->title = 'About';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-about">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        This is the About page. You may modify the following file to customize its content:
    </p>

    <?= $this->render('_part1.php'); ?>
    <?= $this->render('_part2.php'); ?>

    <code><?= __FILE__ ?></code>
</div>
```

Comment: is  just a PHP short notation for echo  http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php .. you can use both ..

Comment: Oooh Thanks!  i wasn't aware of it Thank You

Comment: if you call them without short-tags you need to use `echo $this->render()`  otherwise use short-tags.